# Is it possible to disable Stackdriver logging for Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have set up a small project on Google Cloud Run and I am looking at the costs generated and Stackdriver Logging looks quite expensive. Is it possible to disable it? How? I have not been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Did you ever succeed in cutting costs here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation

[Logging and viewing logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging)

> Cloud Run has two types of logs, and these are **automatically** sent to
> Cloud Logging:
>
> Request logs: logs of requests sent to Cloud Run services. These logs
> are created automatically. Container logs: logs emitted from the
> container instances, typically from your own code, written to
> supported locations as described in Writing container logs.
>
> "Request logs are created **automatically**. Although you cannot control
> the amount of request logs directly from Cloud Run, you can make use
> of the **logs exclusion** feature from Cloud Logging."

Therefore you can not disable the logs of Cloud Run but you can control the amount of logs by using [logs exculusion](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#overview)

Comment: do you have an example of how to create these filters - also does this save on cost?